# VIM - Easymotion return matches from multiple pages

Tags: vim

How can I return a result using emotion in a file for results that show further down in pages of the current file.

Currently I am only matching to the current page view, not full file view. Is this achievable for easymotion or a better solution available?

I can use basic search and the n motion for next however if there are many matches this could be quite annoying.

Update: Found a solution sharing if helpful to others.

Search file

```
/<word>
```

or search word under cursor

```
*
```

select the first result

```
n
```

then if you do this you will get all matching results in the file showing for that word

```
[I
```

More tricks here https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/help/vim/searching.html

Comment: If there was a later match and it's not on-screen, how would you know what to type to jump to it?

Comment: @DanLowe       Yes thats exactly the issue. Was wondering if there was a way to get in file results with easymotion like directory results with CTRL+P

Answer (score 1):

Try using `:vimgrep`:

> `:vim[grep][!] /{pattern}/[g][j] {file} ...`
>
> Search for {pattern} in the files {file} ... and set the error list to the matches. Files matching 'wildignore' are ignored; files in 'suffixes' are searched last. Without the 'g' flag each line is added only once. With 'g' every match is added.

Because `:vimgrep` updates the error list, you can see the full list of matching lines. Open the error window by `:copen` and browse the matches. Also you can navigate between the matches by `:cn` and `:cN`.

I think you want the full list of matches in a file, so try `:vim /pattern/ %`. If you don't want to jump to the first match, add `j` flag to the end of pattern: `:vim /pattern/j %`.

> Without the 'j' flag Vim jumps to the first match. With 'j' only the quickfix list is updated. With the [!] any changes in the current buffer are abandoned.

Comment: also in file if actually use / and search the word select first result and then [I you will get a whole file match of that word.

Comment: @sayth Didn't know that. Thanks for sharing.